Whither a more inclusive site name?
During discussions about a possible merger with the Neuroinformatics proposal see this Meta.cogsci question, on the related discuss.area51 post a comment was made about whether the name of the site is inclusive enough. (More on evidence of name confusion)
While I have always "gotten" that Cognitive Sciences is a great umbrella, I had previously wondered if it was faithful to all facets of the Psychology proposal that was subsumed during the Commitment phase.  With the recent Area 51 discussion, it made me wonder if in a casual search, a web searchers and seekers would consider checking if neuro questions were on topic at a site called Cognitive Sciences, or would they pass us by.  The same question could be asked about, e.g., social psychologists or related fields.  
I have faith that researchers in any of our related fields would be diligent, but given our often "quick" searches for information, time may be a factor, and potential users might move on before having given us a chance.
Where does this leave us?  I don't know.  Maybe we are fine where we are, but I would hope we could consider a few alternatives.  I don't have any concrete suggestions that I would fight for, but perhaps something like "Brain and Behavior" might fill in more corners of the the topic space.
Discussions on alternative names
What do people think of "Cognitive Science and Psychology" as a site title?
"Mind and Brain (Sciences)" as a site title

(Thanks to Ben for suggesting that this be a Meta question)

(Also, we can call it "Brain and Behavio(u)r" if you want ;) )

Darn, you beat me to this question. I was going to use the more Shakespearean "What's in a name?" title. I think this is an important discussion to be had.

Not sure anything is going to be more inclusive than Cog Sci with an s, Brain and Behavior sorta works but it's also in use though it's maybe too generic to be trademarked/confused

Also, as was mentioned in chat (and I thought in the back of my head), brain and behavior sort of seems to exclude Cognition...which has been the main focus of questions on this site, and is often much more popular in casual readers. People should be reading the site every day, and I think cognition stuff is a great way to encourage them to do so as it relates to everyone, not just neuroscientists and researchers.

@BenBrocka I fail to see how "brain" excludes cognition, but I accept your position

@ChuckSherrington B&B happens to be a common title of low-level Psychology courses focusing on the biological and neuroscience related aspects rather than high level cognition. It just sort of evokes a low-level empirical feel. I'm not especially opposed to it either, just pointing it out

@BenBrocka I wasn't married to the name, hehe.  I just always find it intriguing that people want to separate the cognition from the underlying biology, but I think that argument predates the site.

I rather don't...but apparently many do.

For some context on this whole name thing, see this thread on DBA where they're struggling with a very similar naming issue (albeit in a very different domain)

I agree with @BenBrocka "Brain and Behavior" is too reductionist and excludes cognition in the same way that "Cognitive Sciences" was not very welcoming to non-cognition. However, "Brain and Behavior" has a nice ring to it.

@ArtemKaznatcheev How about Jeromy's "Mind, Brain, and Behavior" then?

@ChuckSherrington I commented on his answer, that I think it is too chunky. I would just go for Mind and Brain. Will make a meta suggestion.

@ChuckSherrington okay, here is the formal suggestion

@JoelReyesNoche I'm not sure what you are getting at, could you clarify?  Are you saying because it includes neuroscience (by their definition) that it's already okay?  Or are you saying it really doesn't refer to Anthropology or Education at all, so it's too encompassing?

We are convening next Monday to talk about site name change as well as a new focus for CogSci. Hope you can make it @ChuckSherrington!

@StevenJeuris It will be during my work day, but I will be there in spirit!  I'm excited for everyone.  I haven't had a lot of time over the past couple of years to offer any well-researched answers, but I do pop by from time to time.  Hope all is well with everyone!

Thanks for posting this question. When the site just started I posted a related meta question on how we can present and brand the site so that it is perceived as inclusive to the disciplines that it covers.
Effect of site title "Cognitive Sciences"
I like the "s" at the end of "cognitive science" because it appears to suggest a plurality that reflects our site scope.
That said, I think the current title suggests that the site is about "cognitive science". In some respect the discipline of cognitive science can be seen as subsuming a wide range of other disciplines including psychology (e.g., see the Wikipedia definition as the "scientific study of the mind and its processes". However, if you have ever read a cognitive science journal or attended a cognitive science conference, you will know that the typical interests of such researchers is much narrower than the scope of this site. In particular, the majority of psychology research (i.e., anything not considered cognitive psychology) would typically not fit.
Brainstorming Alternative Titles
In my opinion, a good site title is 

Short
Accurate in communicating scope
Unique

The following are a few brainstormed site titles:

Cognitive Science and Psychology: This is my favourite, I've posted a separate question explaining why I like it and seeking comments.
Brain and Behavior or Mind, Brain, and Behavior: This is inclusive and would readily permit questions about neuroscience, but does not relate as closely to existing canonical disciplinary terms.
Psychological Sciences: This probably has the same issue that "Cognitive Sciences" has. It's fine and good, but may reduce implicit associations with some of topics covered in cognitive science.
Cognitive and Psychological Sciences: This is similar to "Cognitive Science and Psychology" but clarifies that the site is focussed on psychology as "science" rather than self-help and some other connotations of "psychology" on the Internet. It also retains the plural "sciences" which to me connotes the plurality to which the site aspires.


I'm still a proponent of Brain and Behavior. I find it to be the most inclusive one of them all.

@StevenJeuris I quite like it too.

Are there other ways we can emphasize that final S in Cognitive Sciences via the FAQ and copywriting around the site? I love the welcome text idea.

I'm a big fan of "Brain and Behavior" or "Mind, Brain, and Behavior." Probably more the former than the latter. Also perhaps "Brain and Behavioral Science."

I like "Brain and Behavior" but I feel it is too reductionist and might be off-putting to some psychologists, it would be nice to incorporate Mind in there, unfortunately "Mind, Brain, and Behavior" is too clunky...

I second the notion that "brain and Behavior" is too reductive. Cognition is the key underlying object of study within the cognitive sciences, and not having a reference to it in our title could only harm our community.
